# Crontab is not running

Tags: cron, kibana, elk

I tried to schedule crontab for automate kibana dashboard data export, but it's not working.

`crontab -`e is

```
* * * * * /home/rehan/Installation/SIEM/ELK%20/Other/test.sh
```

`test.sh` file has execution permission but the script is not get run every minute. Any suggestions?

Comment: Redirect the output of script to file and check what is inside. Check the cron log. And check if paths in script are absolute and variables are set.

Comment: I have redirect the script to a file when i run the script manually it works fine.

Comment: And what is inside this log?

Comment: What's cronlog and how to check it.Should mention that I'm a beginner in crontab.

Comment: this is text file, usual location is `/var/log/cron` check the last lines with command `tail /var/log/cron`

Comment: There is no cron file in /var/log What should i do??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204711/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-rehan).

Answer (score 0):

Hi `% sign` is special character in crontab.Need to escape this with `backslash \`.

Answer (score 0):

Percent-signs `%` in the command, unless escaped with backslash `\%`,        will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first  will be sent to the command as standard input. There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing `\`.